# Better cluster dendrogram for representation of Cluster in Text Mining in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, text-mining, tm

I have around 1140 terms in three documents (after removing sparse terms). I want to have the information about the clusters. I have produced clusters as shown in attached image but I am unable to read them. I have also tried k-mean clusters but the same problem persists. I am not so much interested in all the terms but clearly defined few three or four clusters would do the job. I have been using tm package in R for text mining.

Secondly I am also looking for finding association in terms with in a single document; for this how can I split a text file into several text files i.e. if my file has three sentences: 
Doc: "My name is ABC. I live in XYZ. I am cousin of TUV."
I would like to split it as:
Doc_1: My name is ABC.
Doc_2:I live in XYZ.
Doc_3: I am cousin of TUV.

So that I have three rows and columns of terms in dtm instead of a single row and column of terms.

[image: Cluster_Dendrogram_Plot1] and [image: Another Format2]

Comment: Please insert the image so we can see it.  Also, what code have you used to do what you describe?

Comment: Click on hyperlinks (1 and 2) on the last line: luster_Dendrogram_Plot1 Another Format2 for images. Code I have used till now : d <- dist(t(dtms_1), method="euclidian")
fit <- hclust(d=d, method="complete")
library(cluster)
d <- dist(t(dtm_1), method="euclidian")
fit <- hclust(d=d, method="complete")
plot(fit, hang=-1) other things that I have tried are K mean clustering, and cutting the tree at specific height but no solution.

Answer (score 2):

You ask more than one question.  I will address your first one.  It seems unrealistic to expect to put 1140 strings in your graph and expect to see anything. You need a way to be able to see a bit of it at a time. You can cut the tree and look a smaller pieces in the lower part of the tree to control how much you are seeing at one time.

Here is an example. Even with 150 points,  it is hard to see what is going on.

```
D = as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(iris[,1:4])))
plot(D)
```

[image: Full tree]

But if you cut the tree,   you can look at individual lower branches and understand that part.

```
Cuts = cut(D, 4)
plot(Cuts$lower[[2]])
```

[image: One Branch]

Of course,  you will need to experiment around a bit to find good places to cut *your* tree.

Comment: Hi....well I am not very much interested in all 1140 terms. I am just interested in information about clusters that is the terms in a particular cluster whether they are important(contextual to the document under study or question under study) or not so important. So even knowledge of terms in cluster in lieu of a dendrogram would serve my purpose. Meanwhile I have decided to manually split the text file and remove the sparse terms leading to lesser number of total terms and then performing clustering which had produced a readable dendrogram.